# how to publish a website in different folder using cruise control

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net

i am able to build a website using cruise control. But i am not able to publish the website in different folder. I am connecting cruise control with TFS. How to publish a website using cruise control?

Answer (score 0):

not sure how TFS affects things, but in your ccnet.config file you should have two nodes for your project: `workingDirectory` and `artifactDirectory`. `artifactDirectory` is where the resulting binaries etc should end up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the project is a Web Application Project, you can add the WebProjectOutputDir argument to your msbuild task in CC.net.

```
<msbuild>
  <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe</executable>
  <workingDirectory>C:\dev\ccnet</workingDirectory>
  <projectFile>CCNet.sln</projectFile>
<buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag /p:WebProjectOutputDir=Output</buildArgs>
  <targets>Build;Test</targets>
  <timeout>900</timeout>
  <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>
```